# I want to hold a filled rectangle in a window, but failed. Please tell me why.

Tags: c++, c, opencv, callback

The code can be built and works, but it does not work as I want. I want to use the mouse to draw a rectangle in a window. When the button is pressed, it starts to draw. When the button is released, the final rectangle should be filled and kept in the window.

I examined the code carefully and I really do not know why it does not work in that way. Please tell me.
**PS: I succeed to realize the functionality by small modification. What I want is just to know what is the problem in this program.**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CvRect rect;
bool g_press = false;

void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);

int main(){
 IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(500, 500), 8, 3);
 cvZero(img);
 cvAddS(img, cvScalarAll(255), img);
 IplImage *temp = cvCloneImage(img);
 cvNamedWindow("FUN");
 cvSetMouseCallback("FUN", my_mouse_callback, (void*) temp);
 cout<<1<<endl;

//if the mouse is pressed, use the statement in while to draw. If the mouse is released, use the callback to draw.
//
 while(1){
 if(g_press) {
 temp = cvCloneImage(img);
 cvRectangle(temp, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), CV_RGB(50,50,50));
 }
 cvShowImage("FUN", temp);
 if(cvWaitKey(15) == 27) break;
 }
 cvReleaseImage(&img);
 cvDestroyWindow("FUN");
}

//callback function for mouse

void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
 IplImage* img = (IplImage*) param;
 switch(event){
 case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
 {
 if(g_press == true){
 rect.width = x - rect.x;
 rect.height = y - rect.y;
 }
 }break;
 case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
 {
 g_press = true;
 rect.x = x;
 rect.y = y;
 rect.height = rect.width = 0;
 }break;
 case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
 {
 g_press = false;
 if(rect.width < 0){
 rect.x += rect.width;
 rect.width *= -1;
 }
 if(rect.height <0){
 rect.y += rect.height;
 rect.height *= -1;
 }

////By this statement, I want to fill the final rectangle and hold it in the window. I examined it for several times and I did not find mistakes. I just want to know the reason.
 cvRectangle(img, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), CV_RGB(50,50,50), CV_FILLED);
 }break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Drop the *thx a lot* from the title.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I observed on Mac OS X: after a rectangle is draw it stays visible until I click with the mouse inside the window again. The reason for that is:

```
if(g_press) {
    temp = cvCloneImage(img);
    cvRectangle(temp, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), CV_RGB(50,50,50));
 }
```

every time a click comes in you clone the original image (which is clear/empty), and that causes you to loose the rectangle that was draw.

If that is what you were expecting, it works on my system.

**EDIT:**

I performed a more complete analysis on your code and the problem is fairly obvious: whatever drawing you do inside `my_mouse_callback()` is undone by the `if` I mentioned before.

If you pay close attention you will notice that the execution of your application goes  like this: `my_mouse_callback()` is called when a mouse event comes in, then it changes the value of `g_press`, configures the `rect` structure with the right params, and finally draws a rectangle on the image.

Immediately after that, the `if` condition inside the `while` is triggered and `temp = cvCloneImage(img);` overwrites the drawing made by the callback: OOPSIE! And then you draw another rectangle, which is not set to be CV_FILLED. In other words, the rectangle you see draw on the window is caused by:

```
if(g_press) {
    temp = cvCloneImage(img);
    cvRectangle(temp, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), CV_RGB(50,50,50));
}
```

and not by the callback! So, to summarize the obviousness, if you want the rectangle to be filled just change this last call to:

```
cvRectangle(temp, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), CV_RGB(50,50,50), CV_FILLED);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works as you said. But it's not what I want. What I want is that when I release the button, the final rectangle is filled. I use the code in the last several lines in the callback to realize it and it seems not to work. Then I test that. It actually works, but the rectangle does not be filled. So I am so confused.

Comment: Updated my answer. When you are done reviewing all the answers, please click on the CHECKBOX near the answer that helped you solve your problem to select it as the official answer to your question. This way you are helping others as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis. However, in the button releasing callback, I firstly set the the global variable     g_press to false. So the statement in     if you mentioned cannot be operated. So I think it won't undo my operation to the     temp in the callback in the case for button released. What's more, the     img variable in the callback function is a local variable. But it represents for     temp that I pass to the callback. Thank you for your careful analysis. I will appreciate if you help me out.

Comment: I already did. Please take the time to test what I suggested to you and you'll see that it works. Go even further, and comment out the `cvRectangle()` call from the callback.

Comment: My analysis may not be accurate, but my test will show you what is actually going on, and how to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understand your meaning. Actually, I did such a modification into the code. I just do not know why this version of code does not work. Maybe I didn't state it clearly in the question. Anyway, thank you a lot for your help. I will vote for your answer.